# Can not activate a virtualenv in GIT bash mingw32 for Windows

Tags: python, git, bash, virtualenv, git-bash

When I try to activate my virtualenv from GIT bash mingw32 I do not get the expected response.

NOTE: `py` is the folder for Python projects in my Google Drive folder. `hy` is the virtualenv folder that was made when I ran `virtualenv --distribute hy`.

```
s3z@s3z ~/Google Drive/py/hy
$ Scripts/activate
```

So you see, there is no expected (hy) that appears before `s3z@s3z ~/Google Drive/py/hy`

```
s3z@s3z ~/Google Drive/py/hy
$ Scripts/activate.bat
Scripts/activate.bat: line 1: @echo: command not found
Scripts/activate.bat: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
Scripts/activate.bat: line 4: `if not defined PROMPT ('
```

And when targeting the actual file name `activate.bat` I get error messages. Then I try deactivating to see what happens cause I thought maybe virtualenv was activated but hidden.

```
s3z@s3z ~/Google Drive/py/hy
$ Scripts/deactivate.bat
Scripts/deactivate.bat: line 1: @echo: command not found
Scripts/deactivate.bat: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
Scripts/deactivate.bat: line 3: `if defined _OLD_VIRTUAL_PROMPT ('

s3z@s3z ~/Google Drive/py/hy
$ Scripts/deactivate
sh.exe": Scripts/deactivate: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Doing `Scripts/activate` runs the script in a new instance of the shell, which is destroyed after the script execution. To run the script in your current shell, use either `. Scripts/activate` or `source Scripts/activate`.

`Scripts/activate.bat` does not work here because it is written in Batch, Windows `cmd.exe` language, and not Bash.

Comment: This is available only on virtualenv 1.7.1 and higher.

Comment: You need to install `virtualenv` separately for this to work. Python 3's built in `python -m venv` command will not create the same `activate` script.

Comment: Is there a way I can add this to the Pycharm terminal path to automatically call it?

Comment: There is a work around that I found through https://github.com/DjangoGirls/tutorial/issues/314#issuecomment-114393488 and https://bugs.python.org/issue22343. Basically copy C:\Python35\Lib\venv\scripts\posix\activate to the C:\Python35\Lib\venv\scripts\nt\ folder before using.

Comment: I used venv and was having trouble getting my environment to work. Using `. env/Scripts/activate` worked, thanks!

Answer (score 16):

## ***How to activate then deactivate a venv with Git Bash***

---

To access your python in Windows 10, you need to add the .exe when creating the virtual environment.

```
$ python.exe -m venv Scripts
```

Then you can move into the Scripts folder you created for the virtual environment.

```
$ cd Scripts/
```

Now you have to call on it to activate the virtual environment.

```
$ source ./Scripts/activate
```

When you are done you just deactivate the virtual environment.

```
$ deactivate
```

[image: Screenshot how to activate/deactivate Git Bash venv]

---

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: I made the edit that you suggested to be more descriptive for the viewers.

Answer (score 8):

On Windows10, you could go in the directory of your virtualenv where the Scripts folder is placed then enter the below command

```
source ./Scripts/activate
```

Note the .(dot) without this it was giving error to me when I use it like above mentioned  then the solution provided by Pierre worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this problem and i found the solution for this.
after you have done

```
$ cd Scripts
```

after this you should just simply type

```
$ source activate
```

and this will activate your venv

to deactivate just type

```
$ deactivate
```

and you venv is deactivated

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error:
in your bash run, this commend:  `source venv/Scripts/activate`
then check if it works using this commend: `pip -V`
I hope that is useful.

Answer (score -1):

Just do  `. Scripts/activate` in your virtual environment folder
[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
Danyal Abbasi@DESKTOP-7I43AM4 MINGW64 /e/Django-projects/studybudproject/studybud/Scripts
$ . activate
(studybud)
Danyal Abbasi@DESKTOP-7I43AM4 MINGW64 /e/Django-projects/studybudproject/studybud/Scripts
$ deactivate

Danyal Abbasi@DESKTOP-7I43AM4 MINGW64 /e/Django-projects/studybudproject/studybud/Scripts
$
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts. That's especially important when there's already an accepted answer that's been validated by the community. Under what conditions might your approach be preferred? Are you taking advantage of new capabilities?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.