# How can I activate a virtualenv in Linux?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, virtualenv, python-venv

I have been searching and tried various alternatives without success and spent several days on it now; it is driving me mad.

I am running on [Red Hat Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux) with Python 2.5.2.
I began using the most recent Virtualenv, but I could not activate it. I found somewhere suggesting I needed an earlier version, so I have used Virtualenv 1.6.4 as that should work with Python 2.6.

### It seems to install the virtual environment ok

```
python virtualenv-1.6.4/virtualenv.py virtual
```

Output:

```
New python executable in virtual/bin/python
Installing setuptools............done.
Installing pip...............done.
```

### The environment looks ok

```
cd virtual
dir
```

Output:

```
bin  include  lib
```

### Trying to activate

```
. bin/activate
```

Output:

```
/bin/.: Permission denied.
```

### I checked chmod

```
cd bin
ls -l
```

Output:

```
total 3160
 -rw-r--r--    1 necrailk biz12        2130 Jan 30 11:38 activate
 -rw-r--r--    1 necrailk biz12        1050 Jan 30 11:38 activate.csh
 -rw-r--r--    1 necrailk biz12        2869 Jan 30 11:38 activate.fish
 -rw-r--r-
```

### It was a problem, so I changed it

```
ls -l
```

Output:

```
total 3160
-rwxr--r--    1 necrailk biz12        2130 Jan 30 11:38 activate
-rw-r--r--    1 necrailk biz12        1050 Jan 30 11:38 activate.csh
-rw-r--r--    1 necrailk biz12        2869 Jan 30 11:38 activate.fish
-rw-r--r--    1 necrailk biz12        1005 Jan 30 11:38 activate_this.py
-rwxr-xr-x    1 necrailk biz
```

### Tring `activate` again

```
. bin/activate
```

Output:

```
/bin/.: Permission denied.
```

Still no joy...

Comment: have you tried "source ~/virtual/bin/activate"?

Comment: From with the directory of your environment do `. bin/activate` and it should work fine.

Comment: I think you just needed to use the `source` command, i.e. `source bin/activate`

Comment: I think you have to do this from the virtualenv directory so first `cd ~/.virtualenvs/*environmentname*` then `source ~/.virtual/bin/activate`

Answer (score 424):

Here is my workflow after creating a folder and `cd`'ing into it:

```
virtualenv venv --distribute
```

Output:

```
New python executable in venv/bin/python
Installing distribute.........done.
Installing pip................done.
```

And

```
source venv/bin/activate
python
```

Comment: ok, tried this no joy
[necrailk@server6 ~/virtual]$ cd
[necrailk@server6 ~]$ $source virtual/bin/activate
source: Undefined variable.
[necrailk@server6 ~]$ sh virtual/bin/activate
[necrailk@server6 ~]$

Comment: Don't type the `$` character, which ii looks like you did here: `[necrailk@server6 ~]$ $source`.  `$` is used to indicate a command prompt.

Comment: Still getiing badly placed ()'s error...what to do?

Comment: same error here :( 
user@mintdesk ~/python_v $ venv/bin/activate
bash: venv/bin/activate: Permission denied

Comment: An alternative to typing 'source' all the time is to use a '.': `$ . venv/bin/activate`

Comment: Use activate.csh instead of activate

Comment: what if there is no /bin/activate file?

Comment: @user1733583 I got the same error, I think the script is a bash file, so make sure you are running it in bash. I receive the error using cshell

Comment: "--distribute DEPRECATED. Retained only for backward compatibility" is shown to me using "virtualenv --help", version 16.6.0. Thus, not necessary anymore?!

Answer (score 131):

You forgot to do `source bin/activate`, where source is an executable name. It struck me the first few times as well. It is easy to think that the manual is telling "execute this from root of the environment folder".

There isn't any need to make `activate` executable via `chmod`.

Comment: OP typed `. bin/activate`. Note the `.`, which is a synonym for `source`.

Comment: "source is an executable name"... which executable? `cmd.exe`? `powershell.exe`?

Comment: I'm trying to activate an environment from cron, and it wouldn't work without being executable (chmod 755).

Comment: activate is just a script and its first two lines say: 1 # This file must be used with "source bin/activate" *from bash*  2 # you cannot run it directly". so I think this should be the accepted answer

Comment: In a cron job you'd want to run the whole thing via `bash -c`. A virtual environment has no meaning outside a shell, so you need to run the shell and pass it a command line that changes to the correct directory and activates the virtualenv, then does whatever else needs doing in the context of the virtualenv. Might be easier to write a short script to do all that if it's at all complex.

Answer (score 107):

You can do

```
source ./python_env/bin/activate
```

Or just go to the directory:

```
cd /python_env/bin/
```

and then

```
source ./activate
```

Answer (score 43):

Go to the project directory. In my case `microblog` is the flask project directory and under `microblog` directory there should be `app` and `venv` folders. then run the below command, This is one worked for me in Ubuntu.

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

[image]

Answer (score 31):

[cd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_(command)) to the environment path, and go to the *bin* folder.
At this point, when you use the [ls](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ls) command, you should see the "activate" file.

Now type

```
source activate
```

Answer (score 25):

Run this code. It will get activated if you are on a Windows machine:

`. venv/Scripts/activate`

Run this code. It will get activated if you are on a Linux or Mac machine:

`. venv/bin/activate`

Comment: it worked with env instead venv on linux for me

Comment: yeah that's good then your venv name is might be env thats why.

Comment: @VitaliyTerziev - in your virtual environment must have been create as env not venv.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62235931/edit) (it covers answers and program input/output as well). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 22):

`mkdir <YOURPROJECT>`: Create a new project

`cd <YOURPROJECT>`: Change directory to that project

`virtualenv <NEWVIRTUALENV>`: Creating a new virtualenv

`source <NEWVIRTUALENV>/bin/activate`: Activating that new virtualenv

Answer (score 21):

The problem there is the `/bin/.` command. That's really weird, since . should always be a link to the directory it's in. (Honestly, unless `.` is a strange alias or function, I don't even see how it's possible.) It's also a little unusual that your shell doesn't have a `.` [builtin for `source`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/dot.html).

One quick fix would be to just run the virtualenv in a different shell. (An obvious second advantage being that instead of having to `deactivate` you can just `exit`.)

```
/bin/bash --rcfile bin/activate
```

If your shell supports it, you may also have the nonstandard `source` command, which *should* do the same thing as `.`, but may not exist. (All said, you should try to figure out why your environment is strange or it will cause you pain again in the future.)

By the way, you didn't need to `chmod +x` those files. Files only need to be executable if you want to execute them *directly*. In this case you're trying to launch them from `.`, so they don't need it.

Comment: Also, you should source `bin/activate`, not `.bin/activate`. Might even work with the `.` then...

Comment: @krlmlr True, I had assumed that was a typo, since in the next line he `cd`s into `bin`.

Comment: hi[necrailk@server6 ~/virtual]$ source bin/activate
Badly placed ()'s.
[necrailk@server6 ~/virtual]$

Comment: korjiro - you were correct  - i did need to find out why environment was odd - it turned out to be a non standard bash implementation- switching to standard bash solved all of the problems

Answer (score 16):

Instead of `./activate`, use `source activate`:

[image: See this screenshot]

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40019665/edit) (it covers answers and program input/output as well). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12):

**For Windows, you can perform it as:**

To create the virtual environment as: `virtualenv envName –python=python.exe` (if not, create an environment variable)

To activate the virtual environment: `\path\to\envName\Scripts\activate`

To deactivate the virtual environment: `\path\to\env\Scripts\deactivate`

It works fine on the new Python version.

Comment: To add clarifying details to this: once you create your virtual environment with `virtualenv venv `, then manually go into the Scripts folder that was created just to look at the files, you'll see some activate files. So that is where we activate it for Windows. So `cd` into your Scripts folder and type `. activate` into your command line (be sure to include a space after the period). You'll notice your path in the command line changes, by adding (venv) to the beginning of your path. This means it's now activated.

Comment: '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 5):

**Windows 10**

In Windows, these directories are created:

[image: Windows 10 virtual environment directories]

To activate the virtual environment in Windows 10.

```
down\scripts\activate
```

The \scripts directory contains the *activate* file.

**Linux Ubuntu**

In Ubuntu, these directories are created:

[image: Linux Ubuntu virtual environment directories]

To activate the virtual environment in Linux Ubuntu.

```
source ./bin/activate
```

The */bin* directory contains the *activate* file.

---

**The virtual environment can be copied from Windows to Linux Ubuntu and vice versa**

If the virtual environment folder is copied from Windows to Linux Ubuntu then according to directories:

```
source ./down/Scripts/activate
```

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) as well. It works wonders for me and how I always have problems with activating.

Comment: hi      source and . (period) seem interchangable         necrailk@server6 ~/virtual]$ source bin/activate
Badly placed ()'s.
this does not seem to work

Comment: my bin permission: _drwxrwxr-x  2 erika erika 4096 2013-01-24 14:37 bin/_

Comment: according to the docs virtuallenvwrapper currently is not tested for python2.5 so not comfortable adding to my possible problems- but thanks

Comment: Just a roundup.  discovered my host was using a non standard shell.  When changed to normal Bash everything worked as it should. now displays virtual env in the prompt and all paths are modified accordinglt.  Many thanks for the help and suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Create your own Python virtual environment called `<your environment _name>:`.

I have given it the name "VE".

```
git clone https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv.git
python virtualenv.py VE
```

To activate your new virtual environment, run (*notice it's not `./` here*):

```
. VE/bin/activate
```

Sample output (*note prompt changed*):

```
(VE)c34299@a200dblr$
```

Once your virtual environment is set, you can remove the `Virtualenv` repository.

Comment: You shouldn't be checking out the master branch of virtualenv and expecting it to actually work. Use a tagged version instead.

Answer (score 3):

On Mac, change the shell to Bash (keep note that virtual env works only in the Bash shell)

```
. venv/bin/activate
```

> `.: Command not found.`

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

> `Badly placed ()'s.`

```
bash
source venv/bin/activate
```

New prompt:

> `(venv) bash-3.2$`

Bingo, it worked. See, the prompt changed.

On Ubuntu:

```
source toolsenv/bin/activate
```

New prompt:

> `(toolsenv) user@local_host~/tools$`

Note: the prompt changed

Comment: Works in zsh too, atleast now

Answer (score 2):

I had trouble getting `source /bin/activate` running, but then I realized I was using [tcsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcsh) as my terminal shell instead of Bash.

Once I switched, I was able to activate *venv*.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error "-sh: 13: source: not found"

Resolution is to first login as sudo

1. `$sudo su`

Then execute the command

2. `#source virtual_env_name/bin/activate`

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same problem. The main reason being that I created the virtualenv as a "root" user.
But later I was trying to activate it using another user.

*[chmod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod)* won't work as you're not the owner of the file, hence the alternative is to use *[chown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chown)* (to change the ownership).

For example, if you have your virtualenv created at `/home/abc/ENV`.

Then [cd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_(command)) to `/home/abc`.

And run the command: **chown -Rv** *[user-to-whom-you want-change-ownership] [folder/filename whose ownership needs to be changed]*

In this example, the commands would be: **chown -Rv abc ENV**

After the ownership is successfully changed, you can simply run **source /ENV/bin/./activate** and your should be able to activate the virtualenv correctly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open a PowerShell window and navigate to your application folder
2. Enter your virtualenv folder, for example: `cd .\venv\Scripts\`
3. Activate the virtual environment by typing `.\activate`

Answer (score 0):

This is for Git Bash running on Windows Server 2022. There is [a question for Git Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450992/can-not-activate-a-virtualenv-in-git-bash-mingw32-for-windows) but it links to here as a duplicate.

Everything works fine after `. my-venv/Scripts/activate` if I stay on the drive with the venv folder. But if I try to work on another drive it falls apart:

```bash
$ which python
/f/\my-venv/Scripts/python
$ cd /c
$ which python
/c/Users/myuser/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python
```

Not sure if this is a known problem or something specific to my system, but in case somebody else runs into it, there it is...

(I worked around it by keeping code & venv on the same drive).