# Keep getting wrong version of Python for my virtualenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

So I am trying to create a virtualenv with the Python version 3.5. I ran this command `virtualenv -p python3.5 myenv` and got this:

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3.5
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in myenv/bin/python3.5
Also creating executable in myenv/bin/python
Please make sure you remove any previous custom paths from your /home/vagrant/.pydistutils.cfg file.
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
```

But when I enter `python` this version shows up instead:

```
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here. Has anybody else ran into this issue?

Edit:
Tried `source myenv/bin/activate` then `python` and still getting the same Python version 3.4

Comment: Can you use anaconda?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't activating `vitualenv`. Try doing:

```
source myenv/bin/activate
```

and run

```
python
```

For more information refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604699/how-to-activate-virtualenv). To better understand about `virtualenv` refer [this guide](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/).