# Module not found with virtual environment

Tags: python

I can run my app from the console that there is in pyCharm but If I try to run my app from a shell my app doesn't find "pymysql" module.

The module is installed in my project in a virtual environment. You can see in the next image how is installed this module.

[image]

And If try to run my app from the shell I've got this error:

[image]

I'm using python3.

What am I doing wrong? Is there any easy way to access to the module?

Comment: Have you activated the virtual environment before trying to run it? It doesn't look like you're in the virtual environment when you run `python3 main.py`.

Comment: How can I activate the virtual environment?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14606360/9374673).

Comment: It works!!! Thank you so much Mihai Chelaru!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways:

1. activate virtual env: `source venv/bin/activate`.
2. directly use specific python: `venv/bin/python main.py`
3. Surely you can temporarily add `venv/bin` to your `PATH`, that's almost the same as the first option: `export PATH=full/path/to/bin:$PATH`

Generally I recommend the first option. But sometimes you may want to use the second one. For example, you want to use this `python` in a crontab script.