# Permission denied in terminal when installing beautifulsoup4 library and pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, beautifulsoup

Tried using Sudo and sudo -I to prompt the terminal for the password, even after entering the password, it does not run.

```
Last login: Fri Jan  4 08:48:43 on ttys000

Kumars-MacBook-Air:~ getyoteam$ pip install BeautifulSoup4
-bash: pip: command not found.

Kumars-MacBook-Air:~ getyoteam$ easy_install pip
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in 
the installation directory:
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-906.pth'
The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory? If the 
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.

For information on other options, you may wish to consult the 
documentation at:

  https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.

Kumars-MacBook-Air:~ getyoteam$
```

What needs to be done in order to add beautifulsoup4 library?

Answer (score -1):

This scenario is exactly what Virtual Environments were built for. Activate one where your code lives and try again.

[activate vent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604699/how-to-activate-virtualenv)