# How to install a module inside a Virtual Environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, xlrd

I am working in a virtual environment and wanted to know how to install modules in it.

In the Ubuntu terminal, I typed `pip install xlrd` but the error came

```
ImportError: Install xlrd >= 0.9.0 for Excel support
```

Comment: You are trying to intall xlrd in system python. First you need to activate your virtual environment.

Comment: Show where your venv are stored.

Comment: This Q/A might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604699/how-to-activate-virtualenv

Comment: `pip install --user  module_name`  may help you, it will install module in your .local directory

Answer (score 1):

**Make virtual environment for your project steps are as follows**
    1.go to specifid directory you want to make project.
    2.open cmd or teminal an type `mkdir testProjectName`.
    3.type `cd testProjectName`.
    4.type `virtual venv`.
    5.type for windows `source venv/scripts/activate`
      type for linux or mac `source venv/bin/activate`
    **# After activating enviroment below are commands to modules you may want to install.**

    6.type `pip install python`.
    7.type `pip install numpy`.
    8.type `pip install matplotlib`.
    9.start your project here.
Hope this helps.....
**NOTE:-** you need to activate enviroment before starting project