# Not able to run in PyCharm but able to run in terminal

Tags: python, pycharm, nltk

I am trying to execute this code in pycharm

```
import nltk

sentence = """ we all are gonna die"""

tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)

print(tokens)
```

But I keep getting this error

```
/Users/yoshithKotla/pythonProject/bin/python /Users/yoshithKotla/Desktop/pythonProject/main.py

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/yoshithKotla/Desktop/pythonProject/main.py", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nltk'
```

But I am able to run the same code using terminal

Comment: Check what enviroment pycharm is running

Comment: PyCharm doesn't automatically include all packages for all projects, you have to go to the project settings and install the packages you want available: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html have you done that yet?

Comment: Note the line `/Users/yoshithKotla/pythonProject/bin/python /Users/yoshithKotla/Desktop/pythonProject/main.py`. This tells you that the python executable being used is located within the same directory as the project, and is probably a virtual environment. You have installed the module globally, but not in this virtual environment.

Comment: how to install the module in virtual environment

Comment: The question lacks debugging details. It doesn't give enough information about how `nltk` is installed. If you are using a venv, or another virtual environment, if you activated that environment and how you are executing the code. see [Install, uninstall, and upgrade packages](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html). Running on the terminal you have to [activate the venv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24720790)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nltk module is installed globally and the python project has no access to it. Changing that setting will solve the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the interpreter PyCharm uses is the same as you are using in your terminal.
( Run > Run... > Edit configurations > Python Interpreter )

Comment: yes its python 3.9 on pycharm same as terminal

Comment: @YoshithKotla Same version does not imply that it's the same interpreter. You need to check the interpreter's path. PyCharm usually creates a new interpreter using a virtual environment (see `venv` module) for each project. There are separate from the system Python installation.