# How can deactivate the virtual environment?

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

The python version in my OS:

```
python3  --version
Python 3.9.2
```

Create a folder with `venv`.

```
python3  -m venv myproject
```

Now i can activate the virtual environment.

```
cd  myproject
~/myproject$ sh  bin/activate
```

I can't deactivate it,no deactivate script in the myproject.

```
tree -r  myproject | rg  deactivate
#Nothing as output

deactivate
bash: deactivate: command not found
```

How can deactivate the virtual environment then?

Comment: You haven't actually activated it properly. You must do e.g. `source bin/activate`. The terminal wil show different prompt when the venv is activated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to activate virtualenv in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604699/how-to-activate-virtualenv-in-linux). (NB: The deactivate command only works inside an active venv).

Answer (score -1):

try writing "`venv name` deactivate"

or you might've not even activated it properly

use:

```
    source bin/activate
```

Answer (score -1):

Show all the steps:

```
debian@debian:~$ python3  -m venv myproject
debian@debian:~$ cd  myproject
debian@debian:~/myproject$ source  bin/activate
(myproject) debian@debian:~/myproject$ deactivate
debian@debian:~/myproject$
```

Done!