# How to get into an active Python Virtual Environment from Git Bash

Tags: python, cmd, virtualenv, git-bash

I have a Python virtual environment with a cloned Github repository inside of it. The repository requires me to run a .sh file. I am using GitBash to run the `sh setup.sh` command.

When I run the .sh file, I get a huge list of "command not found" errors which I think are coming from the fact that my GitBash is not operating in the virtual environment which I activated originally. When I type `$ source ./EnvironmentName.env/bin/activate` into the GitBash, it tells me that there is "No such file or directory".

How do I activate the original environment in my GitBash window?

Comment: I'm not sure if you are running on Windows, but if you are you may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30577271/activating-pyvenv-from-gitbash-for-windows) on how to activate a virtual environment in windows using Git Bash helpful.

Answer (score 0):

if you are on Windows then "Scripts" folder is created instead of "bin"
then the command should be like this:

`$ source ./EnvironmentName.env/Scripts/activate`