# How to tell if virtualenv is activated in Windows Git Bash

Tags: python, virtualenv, git-bash

I created a virtual environment in my new directory with `virtualenv env` and then in Windows Git Bash ran `env/Scripts/activate`, which seemed to work. I didn't notice my virtualenv being displayed in parens at the beginning of the line (question1: can I set it up to work like that?), so to check if it was indeed activated I ran `pip -V` which gave me:
`pip 9.0.1 from c:\tools\python2\lib\site-packages (python 2.7)`

Shouldn't that be giving the directory of my virtualenv rather than site-packages? I also ran `pip list` and it gave me a list of installs that I had (naughtily) installed globally for a different project. So I can only assume my virtualenv did not activate and I don't know why that is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can not activate a virtualenv in GIT bash mingw32 for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450992/can-not-activate-a-virtualenv-in-git-bash-mingw32-for-windows)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your suspicions are correct. Try `source Scripts/activate`. What you did will run the command in a new and temporary shell instance.